# How to obtain deep copies of Julia composite types?

Tags: julia

So here is the setting. I have multiple composite types defined with their own fields and constructors. Lets show two simplified components here:

```
type component1
    x
    y
end

type component2
    x
    y
    z
end
```

Now I want to define a new type such that It can save an array of size K of previously defined composite types in it. So it is a parametric composite type with two fields: one is an integer K, and the other is an array of size K of the type passed.

```
type mixture{T}
    components::Array{T, 1}
    K::Int64

    function mixture(qq::T, K::Int64)
        components = Array{typeof(qq), K}
        for k in 1:K
            components[k] = qq
        end
        new(components, K)
    end
end
```

But this is not the correct way to do it. Because all the K components are referring to one object and manipulating mixture.components[k] will affect all K components. In python I can remedy this with deepcopy. But the deepcopy in Julia is not defined for composite types. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**An answer to your specific question:**

When you define a new type in Julia, it is common to extend some of the standard methods in `Base` to your new type, including `deepcopy`. For example:

```
type MyType
    x::Vector
    y::Vector
end
import Base.deepcopy
Base.deepcopy(m::MyType) = MyType(deepcopy(m.x), deepcopy(m.y))
```

Now you can call `deepcopy` over an instance of `MyType` and you will get a new, truly independent, copy of `MyType` as the output.

Note, my `import Base.deepcopy` is actually redundant, since I've referenced `Base` in my function definition, e.g. `Base.deepcopy(m::MyType)`. However, I did both of these to show you the two ways of extending a method from `Base`.

Second note, if your type has lots of fields, you might instead iterate over the fields using `deepcopy` as follows:

```
Base.deepcopy(m::MyType) = MyType([ deepcopy(getfield(m, k)) for k = 1:length(names(m)) ]...)
```

**A comment on your code:**

First, it is standard practice in Julia to capitalize type names, e.g. `Component1` instead of `component1`. Of course, you don't have to do this, but...

Second, from the [Julia docs performance tips](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/): Declare specific types for fields of composite types. Note, you can parameterize these declarations, e.g.

```
type Component1{T1, T2}
    x::T1
    y::T2
end
```

Third, here is how I would have defined your new type:

```
type Mixture{T}
    components::Vector{T}
    Mixture{T}(c::Vector{T}) = new(c)
end
Mixture{T}(c::Vector{T}) = Mixture{eltype(c)}(c)
Mixture(x, K::Int) = Mixture([ deepcopy(x) for k = 1:K ])
```

There are several important differences here between my code and yours. I'll go through them one at a time.

Your `K` field was redundant (I think) because it appears to just be the length of `components`. So it might be simpler to just extend the `length` method to your new type as follows:

```
Base.length(m::Mixture) = length(m.components)
```

and now you can use `length(m)`, where `m` is an instance of `Mixture` to get what was previously stored in the `K` field.

The inner constructor in your type `mixture` was unusual. Standard practice is for the inner constructor to take arguments that correspond one-to-one (in sequence) to the fields of your type, and then the remainder of the inner constructor just performs any error checks you would like to be done whenever initialising your type. You deviated from this since `qq` was not (necessarily) an array. This kind of behaviour is better reserved for outer constructors. So, what have I done with constructors?

The inner constructor of `Mixture` doesn't really do anything other than pass the argument into the field via `new`. This is because currently there aren't any error checks I need to perform (but I can easily add some in the future).

If I want to call this inner constructor, I need to write something like `m = Mixture{MyType}(x)`, where `x` is `Vector{MyType}`. This is a bit annoying. So my first outer constructor automatically infers the contents of `{...}` using `eltype(x)`. Because of my first outer constructor, I can now initialise `Mixture` using `m = Mixture(x)` instead of `m = Mixture{MyType}(x)`

My second outer constructor corresponds to your inner constructor. It seems to me the behaviour you are after here is to initialise `Mixture` with the same component in every field of `components`, repeated `K` times. So I do this with a loop comprehension over `x`, which will work as long as the `deepcopy` method has been defined for `x`. If no `deepcopy` method exists, you'll get a `No Method Exists` error. This kind of programming is called duck-typing, and in Julia there is typically no performance penalty to using it.

Note, my second outer constructor will call my first outer constructor `K` times, and each time, my first outer constructor will call my inner constructor. Nesting functionality in this way will, in more complicated scenarios, massively cut-down on code duplication.

Sorry, this is a lot to take in I know. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your complete reply. I was familiar with the concept of multiple dispatching but I was not sure if the best way is modifying Base.deepcopy.
Also thanks for the comments. Regarding the third comment and obviating the need to state the type in the constructor, although I managed to use your method but I don't quite understand it!

Comment: @Adham I've updated my answer. If it is still unclear let me know and I'll try again :-)

Comment: Thanks. It is much more clear now (for me as a beginner in Julia :D)