# How to write a function in Julia when the type the arguments are dependent

Tags: julia, bayesian

At the beginning I shall confess that I am a beginner in Julia, so there is a high probability that a better architecture for my problem exists. So, please consider that as well! Anyway, here is the problem.

I am developing a package for Bayesian data analysis.I have started with the simplest model, Bayesian Finite Mixture Model. We assumes the data is generated by a finite number of probability distributions. In Bayesian analysis, we put a prior on the likelihood and call it a Bayesian component.

I have defined a new type for each of these components. For example Gaussian1DGaussian1D, MultinomialDirichlet, ....

```
type Gaussian1DGaussian1D
    μ0::Float64             # mean hyper-parameter
    σ20::Float64            # variance hyper-parameter

    μ::Float64              # mean of the Gaussian1D likelihood
    σ2::Float64             # fixed variance of the Gaussian1D likelihood

    nn::Int64               # number of data points the component contains

    Gaussian1DGaussian1D(μ0::Real, σ20::Real, μ::Real, σ2::Real, nn::Real) = new(μ0, σ20, μ, σ2, nn)
end
Gaussian1DGaussian1D(μ0::Real, σ20::Real, σ2::Real) = Gaussian1DGaussian1D(μ0, σ20, μ0, σ2, 0)
Base.deepcopy(me::Gaussian1DGaussian1D) = Gaussian1DGaussian1D(me.μ0, me.σ20, me.μ, me.σ2, me.nn)   

function logpredictive(me::Gaussian1DGaussian1D, xx::Real)
    # returns the log-predictive of xx given the observed data
    # i.e. log p(xx|x1,...,xn)

    μ, σ2 = posterior(me)
    ll = exp(-(xx - μ)^2 / (2*(σ2 + me.σ2))) / sqrt(2*pi * (σ2 + me.σ2))
    return log(ll)
end
```

and many other functions for each type.

Now I define a FiniteMixtureModel which is parametric:

```
type FiniteMixtureModel{T}
    bayesian_component::Vector{T}  
    K::Int64

    FiniteMixtureModel{T}(c::T, K::Int64) = new([deepcopy(c) for k = 1:K], K)
end
FiniteMixtureModel{T}(c::T, K) = FiniteMixtureModel{eltype(c)}(c, K)
```

This enables me to define a FiniteMixtureModel of previously defined Bayesian components. For example myFMM will be a Mixture model of 5 Gaussian likelihoods with Gaussian priors.

```
myFMM = FiniteMixtureModel(Gaussian1DGaussian1D(1, 1, 1), 5)
```

Now for inference, I define a Gibbs sampler.

```
function gibbs_sampler(fmm::FiniteMixtureModel, xx::Vector{???}, ...)
    # TO BE IMPLEMENTED!
    println("Hi")
end
```

The type of xx depends to the type of the elements of fmm. For example if fmm is a FMM of Gaussian1DGaussian1D, xx would be a vector of Floats. if fmm is a FMM of MultinomialDirichlet, xx would be a vector of integers. The body of the function would be exactly the same for any type(xx). How can I write a function to consider this dependecy between the types of its arguments?

Comment: I may be missing something, but why can't you just use `function gibbs_sampler{T1, T2}(fmm::FiniteMixtureModel{T1}, xx::Vector{T2}, ...)`? Unless there is type-instability somewhere else in your code, there won't be any performance overhead. Or do you want an error check to ensure the type of `xx` is appropriate given the contents of `FiniteMixtureModel`? If so, maybe you could just implement this explicitly as the first line of the function using `T1` and `T2`?

Comment: @ColinTBowers Could you lease elaborate more. I am not familiar with this concept. Will I have to write multiple functions then?

Comment: For any parameterised function eg `f1{T1, T2, ...}(x1::T1, x2::T2, ...)`, a specific (efficient) method is pre-compiled for each given set of specific input types the function is called with at run-time. This pre-compiled efficient method is then used on any subsequent call with the same input types. All this happens "under the hood", so as long as your code is [type stable](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/12/06/writing-type-stable-code-in-julia/) you can just define the function as I did, and Julia will take care of the rest. You only need write one version.

Comment: By the way, I'm still not a huge fan of the way you're building types. As we discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880827/how-to-obtain-deep-copies-of-julia-composite-types) your field `K` seems to be redundant.

Comment: @ColinTBowers, You are right. K is redundant in FiniteMixtureModel, but in the further models that I plan to develop (after getting my head around Julia), I need it. So it is more of a consistency thing.

Comment: why not add xx into FiniteMixtureModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>the type of `xx` should be the same as the type of `bayesian_component` right?</strike>

if you don't want to make `xx` to be a component of `FiniteMixtureModel`(this seems to muddy the waters of your type hierarchy), you can explicitly convert the type of `xx` as a workaround:

```
function gibbs_sampler(fmm::FiniteMixtureModel, xx::Vector, ...)
    xx = oftype(fmm.bayesian_component,xx)
    # TO BE IMPLEMENTED!
    println("Hi")
end
```

however, this may result in some `InexactError`s:

e.g. when `eltype(xx)=Float64`, `eltype(bayesian_component)=Int64`

you can write multiple functions featuring julia's *multiple dispatch*. In this case, you can write:

```
function gibbs_sampler(fmm::FiniteMixtureModel{Gaussian1DGaussian1D}, xx::Vector{Float64}, ...)
    # TO BE IMPLEMENTED!
    println("Hi")
end
function gibbs_sampler(fmm::FiniteMixtureModel{MultinomialDirichlet}, xx::Vector{Int64}, ...)
    # TO BE IMPLEMENTED!
    println("Hi")
end
...
...
```

but this looks redundant. and that's where [parameterised function](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods/#parametric-methods) comes in, which is recommanded by @ColinTBowers.

or you can use a `fill` function to reduce the redundancy:

```
function fill(fmm, xx, ...)
    #TO BE IMPLEMENTED!
    println("Hi")
end
function gibbs_sampler(fmm::FiniteMixtureModel{Gaussian1DGaussian1D}, xx::Vector{Float64}, ...)
    fill(fmm, xx, ...)
end
function gibbs_sampler(fmm::FiniteMixtureModel{MultinomialDirichlet}, xx::Vector{Int64}, ...)
    fill(fmm, xx, ...)
end
...
...
```

Comment: In fact `typeof(xx)` is not the same as `typeof(bayesian_component)`. They are dependent though. eg if 'typeof(bayesian_component)' is `Gaussian1DGaussian1D`, then `typeof(xx)` is `Vector{Float64}`

Comment: @Adham sorry for misunderstanding. i've updated my answer. IMO, if there are not too many kinds of bayesian components, *multiple dispatch* is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks mate. I used Parametric functions, as you and Colin  advised.